# VueJs & Vuetify - V-select outlined

Tags: vue.js, templates, frontend, vuetify.js, v-select

I'm new to VueJS and Vuetify. V-select outlined the label is not placed directly on the border of the field. I have to click in this one first, why ?

My code :

```
<template>
  <v-row>
    <v-col
      cols="12"
    >
      <v-card color="white" variant="elevated">
        <v-form id="frmFilter" class="ma-md-3">
          <v-row class="ma-2 ga-3">
            <v-select
              label="Organismes"
              :items=items
              multiple
              variant="outlined"
              density="compact"
            ></v-select>
              <v-btn density="comfortable" type="submit" color="light-blue-darken-4">Filtrer</v-btn>
              <v-btn density="comfortable" type="submit">Réinitialiser</v-btn>
          </v-row>
        </v-form>
      </v-card>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    items: ['Blue', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Green'],
  }),
};
</script>
```

It gives that :
[image: v-select]

thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by Moritz this is the intended position of the label, but you can use active prop :

```
<v-select
        label="Organismes"
        :items="items"
        multiple
        variant="outlined"
        density="compact"
        active
    ></v-select>
```

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much. I'm so bad, I still need to improve.

Comment: You're not bad you're new, With Vuetify, it's important to always read the documentation for the component you want to use. There are often props you need that you can't guess ;)

Answer (score 0):

Vuetify implements the Material Design specifications, and looking at the [specification of outlined input fields](https://m3.material.io/components/text-fields/specs), you can see that label positions are defined as you describe:

[image]

Comment: THANKS. I have the impression that it is not possible to have the label in the upper left corner as long as we are not focused on the field or I have misunderstood the documentation...